# rm command to remove Angular build files but keep other directories/files

Tags: angular, find, rm

I would need to delete Angular build files and '/assets' folder but keep other files in the directory.

What would be best command line solution for this?

Following should stay:

- /api
- /boardapi
- /thumbnails
- .htaccess
- robots.txt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with deleting the assets folder and then finding all files I need and deleting them.

```
rm -r assets
find . -type f \( -name \*.js -o -name \*.css -o -name \3rdpartylicenses.txt -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.ico -o -name \index.html -o -name \*.woff2 \) -maxdepth 1 -delete -print
```